# Safari extension to notify when downloading is completed

Tags: notification, safari

I am using MacOS Yosemite. There is a default notification, which is that the Download folder "jumps" once. But most times it is easily overlooked

Is there an extension to notify when downloads are finished? Trusted third-party extensions are welcome too!